# vuejs click event displays correct item of array when clicked

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vuejs project where when each of the green boxes is clicked it appends data to the screen. Right now, I get undefined, but ideally it needs display the designated description for the box that is

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    chocs: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", description: "yello" },
      { text: "Learn Vue", description: "white" },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", description: "blue"},
      { text: "Build something awesome", description: "orange" }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    handleTileClick: function(){
$("#fox").append(`<div id="popover-dialog">data here: ${this.choc.description}</div>`);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.main-carousel {
        background: #464646;
        padding-block: 1rem;
      }

      .carousel-cell-container {
        width: 24%;
      }

      .carousel-cell {
        width: 24%;

        position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
      overflow: visible;
 
      }

      .carousel-cell-card {
        height: 200px;
        position: relative;
        background: #8c8;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }

      .carousel-cell .caption {
        text-align: center;
        padding-block: 0.5rem;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color:red;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="(choc,index) in chocs" class="carousel-cell" :key="'chocs-' + index">
<div class="img-icon">
<div class="carousel-cell-card" v-on:click="handleTileClick()"></div>
</div>
<div class="caption">{{ choc.text }}</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="fox">

</div>
```

found in the vue model depending on which box has been selected. any idea why i get undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your event handler you are using `this.choc` which would be undefined because it does not exist in the vue model. You need to pass the `choc` object to your event handler:

```
<div class="carousel-cell-card" v-on:click="handleTileClick(choc)"></div>
```

and then use it there

```
handleTileClick: function(choc) {
  $("#fox").append(`<div id="popover-dialog">data here: ${choc.description}</div>`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the specific item that was clicked as an argument of your function
like this :

```
v-on:click="handleTileClick(choc)"
```

then in your function

```
handleTileClick: function(choc){
    $("#fox").append(`<div id="popover-dialog">data here: ${choc.description} 
    </div>`);
  }
```